# order of Events for Select element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I only tested this so far in chrome browser.

I have the html select element below defined:

**HTML**

```
<select class="ddl" size="5">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

I have the following script:

**Javascript + jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.ddl').change( function () { alert('ddl changed'); });
    $('.ddl').click( function () { alert('ddl clicked'); });
});
```

In the browser, 
- if you quickly click on an item in the list box, you will see that the order of events start with `change` then `click`. 
- if you hold the mouse down for a 10 seconds then release it (long press), `click` fires then `change`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ntX/)

I change the code to below script (add mouseup event),

**Javascript + jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.ddl').change( function () { alert('ddl changed'); });
    $('.ddl').click( function () { alert('ddl clicked'); });
    $('.ddl').mouseup( function () { alert('ddl mouseup'); });
});
```

I get `mouseup`, `change`, then `click` regardless of the speed of the click.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ntX/1/)

Isn't the order of events supposed to stay the same?  Is this a chrome bug?

**UPDATE**

In firefox, `change`, `mouseup`, and then `clicked` on a fast click, and only `click` event is eliminated on a slow click.

In IE11, `change` then `click` is fired on fast click, only `mouseup` is fired on slow click.

**UPDATE with adeneo's suggestion:**

[jsFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ntX/4/)

**Javascript + jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.ddl').change( function () { console.log('ddl changed'); });
    $('.ddl').click( function () { console.log('ddl clicked'); });
});
```

- Chrome: no change
- Firefox: no change
- IE11: no change

[jsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ntX/5/)

**Javascript + jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.ddl').change( function () { console.log('ddl changed'); });
    $('.ddl').click( function () { console.log('ddl clicked'); });
    $('.ddl').mouseup( function () { console.log('ddl mouseup'); });
});
```

- Chrome: no change
- Firefox: no change
- IE11: no change

UPDATE based on Wesley Murch's suggestion:

I have a software package that I am working with.  The software package generates HTML dynamically (template driven).  The feature I am working on is Cascading dropdowns.  There are some dropdowns in that have attributes to show hierarchy. To build the the dependency, I thought I would bind to the change event and call a webservice to update the child dropdown.  Now the dilemma I have is that there is pre-existing code that binds to various events.  I think the pre-existing code has some code that stops processing of subsequent events.  I cannot change that code at the time being.  I always thought that the change event is triggered before the click event.  It works fine if you do a quick click in chrome, but if you hold your mouse down while you think of the selection for a couple seconds my code for cascading dropdown does not get called.

Sorry for the lengthy explanation.

Comment: Now try using `console.log` that doesn't block the thread, and tell us what you get.

Comment: Don't assume mouse events. The select could be changed using the keyboard, so the only safe event is `change`.

Comment: this makes sense for a simple solution.  In a complex environment this cannot be guaranteed (thus my problem). Also, not many users use keyboard when selecting things.

Comment: @adeneo did not seem to make a difference

Comment: In order to get a satisfactory answer, I suggest you give some context and tell us what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: I can't for the life of me reproduce the issue with console logs, the change event always fires before the click event.

Comment: @adeneo I duplicate it every time.  What version of chrome are you running?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ddl').change(function () {
            console.log("change");
        });
        $('.ddl').click(function () {
            console.log("click");
        });
    });
</script>

<select class="ddl" size="1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

order

click select.html:15
change select.html:11
2
click select.html:15
change select.html:11
click